# How to work with .Net 4.X on Unity3D using Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, c#-6.0

I'd like to work on Unity with the scripting runtime version **.NET 4.X using Windows 7**, but when I change the scripting runtime version from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.X, unity starts generating "empty errors in console" which doesn't let me continue, I would appreciate some help, please.

I've tried from Windows 10 and it worked perfectly, but I don't want to use it. I also used 2 different unity versions: Unity 2018.4.1f1 (64-bit) & Unity 2018.4.10f1 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your system locale back to English. Go to Control Panel > Region > Administrative tab > Change system locale > English (United States) > Restart PC.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but sadly it didn't work :(